# How to rotate between multiple forwarding proxies for outgoing requests with golang

Tags: go, post, proxy

I will like to pass a list of forwarding proxy servers for POST request

Currently i am able to do it with just single forwarding proxy

```golang
serverProxy := "http://user:password@123.45.67.89:3128"

request, error := http.NewRequest("POST", httpposturl, bytes.NewBuffer(requestJSON))
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

proxyURL, _ := url.Parse(serverProxy)
proxy := http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)
transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: proxy}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

what i will like to do is pass a list to `url.Parse` and want it to use them using round robin balancing

so something like this

```
serverProxy := "http://user:password@123.45.67.89:3128, http://user:password@223.45.67.89:3128"
```

and then it will select which of the proxy servers to use and rotate them within requests

Is this possible?

> **UPDATE:**

I want to be able to pass the rotated proxy server like this

```
proxyServer := roundRobin("http://round:robin@123.45.67.89:3128, http://robin:round@223.45.67.89:3128")
fmt.Println("proxy server used", proxyServer, "\n")
transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: proxyServer}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a function that uses a for loop to iterate through these proxies?

Comment: and will balance in round robin? mind showing how that will work with an answer? will really appreciate

Comment: @CeriseLimón if you can show this with an answer, will appreciate and happy to accept. One question i have is will it rotate the ips? again an answer will be appreciated

Comment: @uberrebu please check the answer and let me know if needed any help or explanation is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Montage's answer with explanation:

The requirement is to forward request through proxies in round-robin fashion

Since we are using [`http.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) to make request we can look at [`http.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) documentation to see if it provide any support for forwarding request through proxy when we look at the documentation we can see that it does support passing proxy which we can pass through [`http.Transport`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) type which will be passed to [`http.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client). [`http.Transport`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) takes proxy through `Proxy` field which takes in func that return `*url.URL` and `error` there are existing methods like [`http.ProxyURL`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ProxyURL) and [`http.ProxyFromEnvironment`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ProxyFromEnvironment) provided within [`http`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) package that we can use to pass proxies to [`http.Transport`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) but the problem with these methods is that they only take a single proxy server which does not solve our problem at hand and hence we would require to create our own function which takes in multiple proxy servers urls and round-robin between them.

If we look at one of the existing method implemention as our base for creating our own method lets go with [`http.ProxyURL`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ProxyURL) for our case the implementation can be found [`here`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/net/http/transport.go;l=445;drc=e822b1e26e20ef1c76672c0b77b0fd8a97a1fe84). I have copied the implementation below

```golang
func ProxyURL(fixedURL *url.URL) func(*Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    return func(*Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        return fixedURL, nil
    }
}
```

we can see that its a simple closure which takes in single url and return a closure function which then intern return the url passed in as parameter. so we can take it base and create our own round-robin clouse function

```golang
func roundRobin(proxies ...string) func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    var urls []*url.URL
    for _, proxy := range proxies {
        u, err := url.Parse(proxy)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        urls = append(urls, u)
    }

    var mu sync.Mutex
    var i, lenUrls int = 0, len(urls)
    return func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        mu.Lock()
        i = (i + 1) % lenUrls
        u := urls[i]
        mu.Unlock()
        return u, nil
    }
}
```

Lets go over the `roundRobin` function implementation it is a variadic function which takes in proxy url(s) in string format as argument, which internally gets converted to [`url.URL`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL) by parsing the string using [`url.Parse`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Parse) then using the parsed [`url.URL`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL) to create slice of urls `[]*url.URL` which then being used to forward request in round-robin fashion

Complete working example can be found below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func roundRobin(proxies ...string) func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    var urls []*url.URL
    for _, proxy := range proxies {
        u, err := url.Parse(proxy)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        urls = append(urls, u)
    }

    var mu sync.Mutex
    var i, lenUrls int = 0, len(urls)
    return func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        mu.Lock()
        i = (i + 1) % lenUrls
        u := urls[i]
        mu.Unlock()
        return u, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    proxyFn := roundRobin("http://user:password@123.45.67.89:3128", "http://user:password@223.45.67.89:3128")
    transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: proxyFn}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }

    fmt.Println(proxyFn(nil))

    fmt.Println(proxyFn(nil))
}
```

[Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/wxV65iwNSDj)

Another version

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "sync"
)

func praseUrls(proxies ...string) (urls []*url.URL) {
    for _, proxy := range proxies {
        u, err := url.Parse(proxy)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        urls = append(urls, u)
    }
    return
}

func roundRobin(max int) func() int {
    var i int
    return func() int {
        i = (i + 1) % max
        return i
    }
}

func proxyFn(urls []*url.URL) func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    var m sync.Mutex
    fn := roundRobin(len(urls))
    return func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        m.Lock()
        u := urls[fn()]
        m.Unlock()
        return u, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    proxies := []string{"http://user:password@123.45.67.89:3128", "http://user:password@223.45.67.89:3128"}
    urls := praseUrls(proxies...)
    transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: proxyFn(urls)}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/tKD9O38e9yY)

**Note:** It would be better to pass proxy urls from env variable which would help in case any proxy server changes or new are added

Comment: just tested the 1st version and worked like a charm!!!, will test second version later but man so grateful once again..thanks a lot!!!

Comment: based on 1st version answer, how is it able to remember last poxy server used? is `roundRobin` function storing stuffs in memory? is that what the `sync` packages does?

Comment: @uberrebu yes `roundRobin` funtion is a closure which is calculating and storing the last index used and when called next time it returns new index which is used to retrieve url from the slice it is like per request uses different proxy server to forward the request.

Answer (score 3):

Create a proxy function that round-robins through your proxy URLs.  Use that function in your transport:

```
func roundRobin(urls []*url.URL) func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var i int
    return func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        mu.Lock()
        i = (i + 1) % len(urls)
        u := urls[i]
        mu.Unlock()
        return u, nil
    }
}


transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: roundRobin(yourProxyURLs)}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

Comment: how will the variable  `yourProxyURLs` look like?

Comment: @CeriseLimón i get this error message `cannot use yourProxyURLs (variable of type []string) as type []*url.URL in argument to roundRobin`

Comment: here is go playground link https://go.dev/play/p/K1sNs6O4ISt @CeriseLimón

Comment: i dont understand why @CeriseLimón keeps removing his comments. He comments and then deletes the comment later, making it difficult for others to read comments

Comment: i switched to use string instead of url.URL, and here is what i get https://goplay.tools/snippet/s0v6tDyluJu

Comment: its ok to leave comment; people read them to follow along discussions. no need to delete; the FBI/CIA are not watching much

Comment: why not post an answer? will be appreciated. i posted links to all code i have tested, you can also modify what i have in the go playground also

Comment: it does not work, if it works i would mark as answer already. did you see all the go playgrounds i shared? i am still in need of help here

Comment: too much CENSORSHIP going on..feel free to delete this comment also and have fun

Comment: why not send me a playground of what works? will save your time and mine also, win-win

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Montage's answer with code to parse a string.

```
func roundRobin(serverProxy string) func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    parts := strings.Split(serverProxy, ",")
    var urls []*url.URL
    for _, part := range parts {
        u, err := url.Parse(strings.TrimSpace(part))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        urls = append(urls, u)
    }
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var i int
    return func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        mu.Lock()
        i = (i + 1) % len(urls)
        u := urls[i]
        mu.Unlock()
        return u, nil
    }
}

serverProxy := "http://user:password@123.45.67.89:3128, http://user:password@223.45.67.89:3128"
transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: roundRobin(serverProxy)}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

Comment: please check this playground with your code https://goplay.tools/snippet/KKmN9YbVTEG why cant i get the out of the ips when i call the function?

Comment: above comment???

Comment: why not send me a playground of what works? will save your time and mine also, win-win

Comment: @CeriseLimón i also added what i want to do under UPDATE section of the question; please have a look...why is it that you have to loop again to get what proxy server is used? why not just have the roundRobin function do that from the list passed to it already? and let it be the one to give the rotated proxy server? `at the moment it only uses first ip in the list and does not rotate` please see this and see output https://go.dev/play/p/bGz58k6Omnt

Comment: i have used this `transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: roundRobin(yourProxyURLs)}` and still does NOT work..it is getting frustrating i didn't realize this is a very difficult thing to do. I send goplayground of trying to output rotated ips without looping, let us rotate from the list...i try to explain what i am doing and trying to do but just frustrating going back and forth as if am not clear enough..did you check my last comment and the goplayground link i added?

Comment: @CeriseLimón no need for back and forth, just use goplayground with answer; currently you are looping but i want the function to do the loop and get me a rotated ip from the list given to it...just use goplayground so we dont keep going back and forth, not sure about you but its getting tiring...appreciate your help..thanks

Comment: yes it rotates through the proxies in your code but i am not using it that way in my app code. I am not running loop when making POST requests for example, i make requests one at a time...so what happens is it keeps using same proxy from the list, usually it picks the second proxy server in the list and just re-uses same proxy server...so maybe this is not possible

Comment: @CeriseLimón so seems there has to be some type of data stored in memory to know what proxy server was used last or something else it will always keep giving same proxy server because requests are made one at a time and not in loops

Comment: the code in my question, i am making a POST request. Please check my question to see how i want to and how i am using the code..test your code with the making a POST request like i have in the question, you will see the same IP or proxy server get used every time you make the PSOT request