# How do i properly get struct items from stripe subscription response object?

Tags: json, go, stripe-payments

I am trying to grab some data from the struct of the stripe response objects for subscriptions. Here is link to the structure of the response object [stribe subscription object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object)

Here is what i have and what am trying to do

```
type SubscriptionDetails struct {
    CustomerId             string  `json:"customer_id"`
    SubscritpionId         string  `json:"subscritpion_id"`
    StartAt                time.Time  `json:"start_at"`
    EndAt                  time.Time  `json:"end_at"`
    Interval               string  `json:"interval"`
    Plan                   string  `json:"plan"`
    PlanId                 string  `json:"plan_id"`
    SeatCount              uint8  `json:"seat_count"`
    PricePerSeat           float64  `json:"price_per_seat"`
}



func CreateStripeSubscription(CustomerId string, planId string) (*SubscriptionDetails, error) {

    stripe.Key = StripeKey

    params := &stripe.SubscriptionParams{
    Customer: stripe.String(CustomerId),
    Items: []*stripe.SubscriptionItemsParams{
        &stripe.SubscriptionItemsParams{
        Price: stripe.String(planId),
        },
    },
    }
    result, err := sub.New(params)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    data := &SubscriptionDetails{}

    data.CustomerId           = result.Customer
    data.SubscritpionId       =  result.ID
    data.StartAt              =  result.CurrentPeriodStart
    data.EndAt                =  result.CurrentPeriodEnd
    data.Interval             =  result.Items.Data.Price.Recurring.Interval
    data.Plan                 =  result.Items.Data.Price.Nickname
    data.SeatCount            =  result.Items.Data.Quantity
    data.PricePerSeat         =  result.Items.Data.Price.UnitAmount


    return data, nil    
}
```

there are some items that are easy to get directly like `ID` field i got easily with `result.ID` and no complaints but for other items here are the error messages am getting

```
cannot use result.CurrentPeriodStart (type int64) as type time.Time in assignment
...
cannot use result.Customer (type *stripe.Customer) as type string in assignment
...
result.Items.Data.price undefined (type []*stripe.SubscriptionItem has no field or method price)
```

So how do i get the data for `data.CustomerId` and `data.PricePerSeat`?

UPDATE:

here is structure of the subscription object from stripe

```
type FilesStripeCreateSubscription struct {
    ID                    string      `json:"id"`
    CancelAt             interface{}   `json:"cancel_at"`
    CancelAtPeriodEnd    bool          `json:"cancel_at_period_end"`
    CanceledAt           interface{}   `json:"canceled_at"`
    CurrentPeriodEnd     int64         `json:"current_period_end"`
    CurrentPeriodStart   int64         `json:"current_period_start"`
    Customer             string        `json:"customer"`
    Items                struct {
            Data []struct {
                    ID                string      `json:"id"`
                    BillingThresholds interface{} `json:"billing_thresholds"`
                    Created           int64       `json:"created"`
                    Metadata          struct {
                    } `json:"metadata"`
                    Object string `json:"object"`
                    Price  struct {
                            ID               string      `json:"id"`
                            Active           bool        `json:"active"`
                            Currency         string      `json:"currency"`
                            CustomUnitAmount interface{} `json:"custom_unit_amount"`
                            Metadata         struct {
                            } `json:"metadata"`
                            Nickname  string `json:"nickname"`
                            Object    string `json:"object"`
                            Product   string `json:"product"`
                            Recurring struct {
                                    AggregateUsage interface{} `json:"aggregate_usage"`
                                    Interval       string      `json:"interval"`
                                    IntervalCount  int64       `json:"interval_count"`
                                    UsageType      string      `json:"usage_type"`
                            } `json:"recurring"`
                            TaxBehavior       string      `json:"tax_behavior"`
                            TiersMode         interface{} `json:"tiers_mode"`
                            TransformQuantity interface{} `json:"transform_quantity"`
                            Type              string      `json:"type"`
                            UnitAmount        int64       `json:"unit_amount"`
                            UnitAmountDecimal int64       `json:"unit_amount_decimal,string"`
                    } `json:"price"`
                    Quantity     int64         `json:"quantity"`
                    Subscription string        `json:"subscription"`
                    TaxRates     []interface{} `json:"tax_rates"`
            } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"items"`
}
```

Comment: still in need of help, the other person refused to respond to comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first go over the code which works under the hood, what is being returned and then we look at the problems one at a time.

When we call [`sub.New()`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscription/client.go#L29) method with `params` it returns [`Subscription`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscription/client.go#L30) type

**Note:** I will only show limited definition for types since adding the complete structure will make the answer big and not specific to the question context

Lets Look [`Subscription`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscription.go#L654) type

```golang
type Subscription struct {
  ...
  // Start of the current period that the subscription has been invoiced for.
  CurrentPeriodStart int64 `json:"current_period_start"`
  // ID of the customer who owns the subscription.
  Customer *Customer `json:"customer"`
  ...
  // List of subscription items, each with an attached price.
  Items *SubscriptionItemList `json:"items"`
  ...
}
```

Let looks over the first error

```
cannot use result.CurrentPeriodStart (type int64) as type time.Time in assignment
```

According to the [`Subscription`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscription.go#L654) type we can see `CurrentPeriodStart` is of type `int64` while you are trying to set it to `StartAt` field of `SubscriptionDetails` type which is of type [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) since the types are different one type cannot be assigned to other, to solve the issue we need to explicitly convert it to [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) which can be done as follows:

```golang
data.StartAt = time.Unix(result.CurrentPeriodStart, 0)
```

[`time.Unix`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Unix) method creates [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) type from the passed `int64` value and return which we can assign to `StartAt` field

Now lets move on to the second error

```
cannot use result.Customer (type *stripe.Customer) as type string in assignment
```

As we can see from [`Subscription`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscription.go#L654) definition `Customer` field is of type [`*Customer`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/customer.go#L272) it is not string type since you are trying to assign [`*Customer`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/customer.go#L272) type to `CustomerId` field of string type which is not possible that causes the above error, referred data is incorrect then where is the correct data the correct data is available inside [`*Customer`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/customer.go#L272) type withing `ID` field which can be retrieved as follows

```golang
data.CustomerId = result.Customer.ID
```

Lets go over the last error

```golang
result.Items.Data.price undefined (type []*stripe.SubscriptionItem has no field or method price)
```

Again if we look at [`Subscription`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscription.go#L654) definition we can see `Items` field is of type [`*SubscriptionItemList`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscriptionitem.go#L136) type and if we look at [`*SubscriptionItemList`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscriptionitem.go#L136) definition

```golang
type SubscriptionItemList struct {
    APIResource
    ListMeta
    Data []*SubscriptionItem `json:"data"`
}
```

It contains a field name `Data` and `Data` is of type `[]*SubscriptionItem` notice it is slice `[]` of [`*SubscriptionItem`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscriptionitem.go#L98), which is the cause of the error since `Data` field is slice of [`*SubscriptionItem`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscriptionitem.go#L98) we can solve the problem as below:

```golang
data.PricePerSeat = result.Items.Data[0].price.UnitAmount
```

There are few more errors which can occur that I would like to point out please continue reading below to solve those issue

Now lets look at [`*SubscriptionItem`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/subscriptionitem.go#L98) definition

```golang
type SubscriptionItem struct {
  ...
  Price *Price `json:"price"`
  ...
}
```

It contains [`Price`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/price.go#L393) field notice the name starts with capital letter and in shared code it is referred with small letter which can cause another issue and finally if we look at [`Price`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/price.go#L393) definition

```golang
type Price struct {
  ...
  // The unit amount in %s to be charged, represented as a whole integer if possible. Only set if `billing_scheme=per_unit`.
  UnitAmount int64 `json:"unit_amount"`

  // The unit amount in %s to be charged, represented as a decimal string with at most 12 decimal places. Only set if `billing_scheme=per_unit`.
  UnitAmountDecimal float64 `json:"unit_amount_decimal,string"`
  ...
}
```

It contains `UnitAmount` field which is what we are using, but there is a catch here `UnitAmount` is of type `int64` but `PricePerSeat` is of type `float64` assigning different type to each other will again cause error so either you can convert `int64` to `float64` or even better you can use `UnitAmountDecimal` field available within [`Price`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/96d9eb694e24d9704164b0113021a21eaf7978e7/price.go#L393) type containing the same data in `float64` format which will reduce the explicit conversion that we would have to do when using `UnitAmount` field, so as per the explanation we get below solution

```golang
data.PricePerSeat = result.Items.Data[0].Price.UnitAmountDecimal
```

Comment: very comprehensive answer, i did solve the other 2 errors from the other answers but great explanation..thanks a lot

Comment: have another question i still need help with if you willing https://stackoverflow.com/q/73423278/5442187 thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the 3 errors you have mentioned

1. `cannot use result.CurrentPeriodStart (type int64) as type time.Time in assignment`

Type of `result.CurrentPeriodStart` is int64 and you are trying to set it into a field of type `time.Time`, which will obviously fail.
[The API is sending the time in unix format](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-current_period_end), which you need to parse to get it into time.Time. Do this for other time fields also

```
data.StartAt = time.Unix(result.CurrentPeriodStart, 0)
```

2. `cannot use result.Customer (type *stripe.Customer) as type string in assignment`

Similar issue as above, the field `result.Customer` is of type `*stripe.Customer` while you are trying to set it into a field of type `string`. [Customer ID is a field inside the struct `Customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object)

```
data.CustomerId = result.Customer.ID
```

3. `result.Items.Data.price undefined (type []*stripe.SubscriptionItem has no field or method price)`

`stripe.SubscriptionItem` struct does not have a field `price`. I am not sure what you want here. I suggest reading the [subscriptions object documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object).

Comment: i added the structure of the subscription object under UPDATE. you mind having a look again please?

Comment: 2. there is `Customer` in the subscription object also, please check the response struct i posted in UPDATE section

Comment: 3. the error message does not show the fill path e.g `result.Items.Data.Price.UnitAmount` i put there; please check the response struct i posted

Comment: This answer is correct and @uberrebu you should look at the data structure carefully. result.Items.Data is an array, so you can't do result.Items.Data.xxx

Comment: so what is proper way to get the value? need help with that

Comment: @orakaro can you post answer how to get the value from the struct?

Answer (score 1):

To access the price `result.Items.Data[0].Price.UnitAmount`

If you use a debugger, just put a breakpoint after the `sub.New` line and explore the content of the result variable

Comment: what about this error. `cannot use result.Customer (type *stripe.Customer) as type string in assignment`

Comment: accessing price with `result.Items.Data[0].Price.UnitAmount` worked..thanks!...now just need to figure out how to get `result.Customer`...error currently is `cannot use result.Customer (type *stripe.Customer) as type string in assignment`

Comment: @uberrebu probably you need "data.CustomerId = result.Customer.ID"